# calling a JavaScript function on Asp.net textBox

Tags: javascript, formatting

Please help! i have been trying to call this function on my Asp.net textbox to format users input while typing.

```
function format(number) {            
        var decimalSeparator = ".";
        var thousandSeparator = ",";

        var result = String(number);
        var parts = result.split(decimalSeparator);
        if (!parts[1]) {
            parts[1] = "00";
        }
        result = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("");
        result = result.replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g, "$1" + thousandSeparator);
        parts[0] = result.split("").reverse().join("");
        return parts.join(decimalSeparator);
    }
// i tried using onkeyup, it didnt work
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTransport" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxes" onKeyup="javaScript: format(this);"></asp:TextBox>

// also i tried using onChange, it didnt work.
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTransport" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxes" onChange="javaScript:format(this);"></asp:TextBox>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        txtTransport.Attributes.Add("onKeyup", "javaScript: format(this);");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from javascript, not in codebehind !

```
var el = document.getElementById("<%= txtTransport.ClientID %>");

el.onkeyup = function(e) {
    // Do stuff
};
```

But I think your function is logicaly wrong. Try it anyway. Your ID of a server side control is not exactly the same you write in the code, for get the real ID you can use `<%= txtTransport.ClientID %>`.

Comment: Please what is wrong with my function, i have tried your code but didnt work. im trying format 1000 to 1,000.00---10000 to 10,000.00 etc as the user types. do you have any code dat can help?

Comment: @Henry The function probably work correctly (and it seems to work), but when I say "is logicaly wrong" I want to say this: https://jsfiddle.net/qn8zhud7/1/ Check the two different event. Your goal I think is onblur (the lost focus), and not the keyup event.